# Use ROW FUNCTION in cell

Tags: excel, row

I have the following code

`=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('Combined Page'!I:I,(MATCH('Load & Unload (7)'!A272,'Combined Page'!A:A,0)))>=35,"Completed","Available"),"")`

Instead of having A272 I wanting to use A then row()

How would I write this?

Thanks

Comment: Using 

ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())

Returns the cell reference, how would I add that to my code?

Comment: Hi pnut as I explained in the code instead of A272 I am wanting to put the cell reference so if a user moves it from row a272 to another row it picks that up

Comment: An example is  =MATCH(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-14,4),'Combined Page'!A:A,0) returns #N/A.   Yet.    =MATCH(A8,'Combined Page'!A:A,0) works . Yet even though ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-14,4) = A8   Strange

Comment: As @pnuts suggests, try `=MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-14,4)),'Combined Page'!A:A,0)`

Comment: Yep works a treat thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested

=MATCH(INDIRECT("'Load & Unload (7)'!A"&ROW()),'Combined Page'!A:A,0)

Works.  Thanks